# How test eventChannel in redux-sagas?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, unit-testing, redux, redux-saga

I am new with unit testing and redux/sagas. I would like to know the proper way to test a eventChannel.

I created a project in react-native where I have an authentication flow with firebase. I would like to have some guidance of What is need to be tested and how addressed?

Here is my saga:

```
export function createAuthListener() {
  return eventChannel(emit => {
    const listener = (user: any) => {
      emit({ user });
    };

    const suscribe = auth.authListener(listener);

    return suscribe;
  });
}

export function* handleAuthChange({ payload }: { payload: any }) {
  try {
    const { user } = payload;

    if (user) {
      console.log({ user }, user.email);
      const profile = {
        email: user.email,
        name: user.displayName,
        profileImg: user.photoURL
      };
      yield put(profileActions.setData(profile as unknown as ProfileType));
      yield call(navigatorDispatch, StackActions.replace('Home'));
      return;
    }

    yield put(profileActions.setData(null));
    yield call(navigatorDispatch, StackActions.replace('Auth'));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(AUTH_TAG_LOG, 'Error::signIn', { error });
  }
}

export function* onAuthStateChange() {
  const chan = yield call(createAuthListener);
  try {
    while (true) {
      // take(END) will cause the saga to terminate by jumping to the finally block
      let payload = yield take(chan);
      yield call(handleAuthChange, { payload });
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(AUTH_TAG_LOG, 'Error:onAuthStateChange', { error });
  } finally {
    console.log(AUTH_TAG_LOG, 'Finally onAuthStateChange');
  }
}

export default function* () {
  yield call(onAuthStateChange);
}
```

Comment: What's `auth.authListener`? How does it work? When does the `listener` be called.

Comment: The auth.authListener is a listener that receive a authentication events (error, authentication success). As you can see that listener is called when the sagas runs